# No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. To create a dropdown with the data from database

Tags: flask, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I've been spending hours and hours searching on the internet for a solution to this problem.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

At the moment, I'm trying to build a web to manage students. What I'd like to do with this is to create multiple classrooms to which students will belong. Each classroom, therefore, will have some students separately as a result.

For this, I created a DB in a file using flask_sqlalchemy and then two modules (student, and classroom) in another like below

```
class StudentModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "students"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    year = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    school = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    classroom_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("classrooms.id"))
    classroom = db.relationship("ClassroomModel")

class ClassroomModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "classrooms"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    students = db.relationship("StudentModel", lazy="dynamic")
```

Then, added some classrooms for a test, which worked fine up to this stage.

It was right after forms were created when this problem began to happen

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, Length, ValidationError

from models import ClassroomModel, StudentModel


YEAR_CHOICES = [("", '<<Choose Student Year>>'), ('Year 1', 'Year 1'), ('Year 2', 'Year 2'), ('Year 3', 'Year 3')]
SCHOOL_CHOICES = [("", '<<Choose Student School>>'), ('Yang-san', 'Yang-san Secondary School'),
                  ('Ji-san', 'Ji-san Secondary School'), ('Yong-doo', 'Yong-doo Secondary School'),
                  ('Korea', 'Korea Secondary School')]

CLASSROOM_CHOICES = [(classroom.id, classroom.name) for classroom in ClassroomModel.query.all()]

def validate_selection(form, field):
    if field.data == "":
        raise ValidationError("Make sure to choose an option")


class StudentForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Student Name',
                       validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Student Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    year = SelectField('Student Year',
                       choices=YEAR_CHOICES,
                       validators=[validate_selection]
                       )
    school = SelectField('Student School',
                         choices=SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                         validators=[validate_selection]
                         )
    classroom = SelectField('Student Classroom',
                            choices=ClassroomModel.get_all_classroom())
    submit = SubmitField('Add Student')
```

When I tried to run an app with the code above, it gave me this error message.
[image]

What I've figured out from a few experiments is that it is this line

**

> CLASSROOM_CHOICES = [(classroom.id, classroom.name) for classroom in
> ClassroomModel.query.all()]

**

that's causing such errors because that line deleted wouldn't pose any error any longer.

I don't know what I did wrong, but all I wanted to do was just give a classroom id to each student as a foreign key so that when I can make use of it when I create an individual classroom page, it can display a list of students who belong to the classroom on that page to manage their attendance or so. Please, can anyone guide me through this headache? Any help will be appreciated immensely

[image]

( classrooms are already in the database by the way with their own ids just in case if it might give you any additional clues)

Answer (score 2):

The line: `CLASSROOM_CHOICES = [(classroom.id, classroom.name) for classroom in ClassroomModel.query.all()]`  causes this error because it is out of the *app context* where the app context would be any part of your code that uses the `app = Flask(__name__)` as a decorator such as your routes.

To get rid of the error, you can simply modify your line as follows:

```
def get_classrooms():
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        return [(classroom.id, classroom.name) for classroom in ClassroomModel.query.all()]

CLASSROOM_CHOICES = get_classrooms()
```

Also if you have initiated our *app* and *db* in a separate file, ensure you've imported them in this file.

Comment: I haven't been able to get on Stack for a while so just checked this comment. I now clearly see what the reason causing the trouble was. My belated appreciation. Thank you so much for this explanation!